# How to update an Angular Resource in a form

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application where I display a list of users. The users are retrieved with a

```
$resource.query()
```

A user can be edited by clicking on the list, which opens an edit-popup.

How can I update the resource, while also allowing the user to cancel the edit-popup and revert any changes?

I.e if the edit-popup works directly with a $resource-retrieved object, how can I "undo" any changes if the user cancels the edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a UserEditController defined on your popup element and is a child of UserController.
You can make a copy of the user when the popup opens.

```
this.UserEditController = function($scope) {
   var previous_attributes = angular.copy($scope.user)

   var close = function() {
      $scope.mode = 'show';
   }

   $scope.cancel = function() {
      angular.extend($scope.user, previous_attributes);
      close();
   }

   $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.user.save();
      close();
   }

}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="user" ng-controller="UserController">
  <strong>{{ user.name }}</strong>
  <button ng-click="editUser()">Edit</button>


  <ng-switch on="mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="edit" class="edit-user form" ng-controller="UserEditController">
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"> 
      <button ng-click="cancel($event); $event.preventDefault();">Cancel</button>
      <button ng-click="save($event); $event.preventDefault();">Save</button>
    </div>
  </ng-switch>

</div>
```

If you are using a directive to open the popup, you can define a controller for the directive and do the copying there, which will make it reusable.